# Bamboo use variable from script task in webhook

Tags: webhooks, bamboo

I'm creating a build webhook and need to get the value of a variable from a script task.
In the documentation they mention that you can use system variables with

```
${system.VAR}
```

however when I `export TEST="TEST"` in the script and try to get `${system.TEST}` in my bamboo webhook template the webhook does not get sent.

I need to get the container ID which is created in the script and accessible as a variable into my webhook. Does anyone know how to do this?